# is there something in laravel that will help me build a django like bullet proof admin backend with rules for users?

Tags: php, laravel

now don't tell me "well the use case depends on your app" there is millions of apps written in django, and all make use of djangos admin features. I know laravel is not a CMS, but I am writing an app from scratch. I want to get bullet proof user roles and rights depending on the user. Is there some scaffolding i can use that comes with it maybe?

Comment: oh, so you guys telling me there exists nothing? ok

Answer (score 2):

this is one you can check for laravel admin, I don't know django so don't know how you work with its admin and flow but this is one package you can check.
[laravel-admin](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator)

this can help for laravel admin but not sure like django.

And if you are looking for build in CMS than these are links.

1. [October CMS](https://octobercms.com)
2. [Asgard CMS](https://asgardcms.com)
3. [Lavalite](http://www.lavalite.org)
4. [PyroCMS](https://pyrocms.com)